# how to install phpmyadmin in ubuntu server

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I try to install phpmyadmin in ubuntu server 12.10 , i have try `apt-get update` then `apt-get install phpmyadmin` and i have folowing error

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin
```

this my /etc/apt/sources.list view

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

 ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
 ## distribution.
 deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
 deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

 ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
 ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
 ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
 deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
 deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
 deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
 deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main restricted      universe multiverse
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-backports main  restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main
```

any help?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 has reached end-of-life: http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2014/05/01/ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal-reaches-end-of-life-on-may-16-2014/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this;

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 3):

In Linux ( Ubuntu ) first, we need to update and upgrade using the following commands

`sudo apt-get update` 
`sudo apt-get upgrade`

then you can run the following command to install phpmyadmin

`sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`

it will ask username and password for the account

Comment: Cool, Nice to hear @SatheeshKumar

Answer (score 2):

**First**: ensure the list of available packages is up to date before installing anything new.

```
sudo apt-get -y update

apt-get -y install phpmyadmin
```

**Second**: At the first screen, **select apache2 by using the space bar**, then hit enter to continue.

At the second screen, which asks “configure the database for phpmyadmin with dbconfig-common?”, select Yes, then hit enter to continue.

At the third screen **enter your MySQL password**, then hit enter to continue.

**Third**: Add the following to the bottom of the file   "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf":

```
# phpMyAdmin Configuration
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

save and close the apache.conf file

And, Last :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now it's done.